# how to incorporate grunt-vulcanize into the chromeapp yeoman generator's Gruntfile.js?

Tags: gruntjs, google-chrome-app, polymer, yeoman-generator

I am trying to make a chromeapp incorporating some polymer elements - polymer-list and one of my own.

I started with the [yeoman chromeapp generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-chromeapp), but it didn't take long before I ran into some csp issues and I found that I should be using the [vulcanize tool](https://github.com/Polymer/vulcanize). When I try that using the command line version, it seems to work nicely.

Then I started to want that done automatically for me in the build process, and so I had a look at adding it to the Gruntfile.js which was generated by the chromeapp yeoman generator. I found the [grunt task](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-vulcanize) and it provides instructions for adding it to the Gruntfile.js.

However, one thing I learned about the Yeoman generator is that the developer is supposed to debug their app in the app/ directory, and only 'build' when building an optimised version (presumably for distribution). Thinking about it, the vulcanize step seems to be necessary even for debugging (since polymer won't work out-of-the-box in a chromeapp due to the csp), and so it is an intermediate step. As such, it's a bit more effort for a beginner (part of the audience for Yeoman, I presume).

So, now I'm wondering how to do this. It does seem like something someone's already done, but I can't find any examples.

I have worked on some [projects](https://01.org/html5webapps/webapps) that use a 2-step grunt build process (due to having several targets mostly), so that the flow is something like this : app/ -> build/app -> app/crx. IINM, the first step simply brings all the bits together plus substitutes app names and version numbers/etc; and the second step does the optimisation (uglify/minify/etc).
I guess the solution to this question is to do something similar, and debugging/development is done on the build/app in the middle step.

I've done some fiddling with grunt in the webapp projects I reference (and even wrote [one](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-crosswalk)), but the plugins used by this generator aren't very familiar to me.

My question, then, is has anyone has done this already, or corrections if I have misunderstood anything/etc. Also, if someone has suggestions on how to integrate the grunt vulcanize task into the Gruntfile.js provided by the chromeapp Yeoman generator, then I'll give is a try.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a solution myself and came up with [this](https://github.com/davidmaxwaterman/yeoman-chromeapp/blob/master/Gruntfile.js).

The solution is somewhat involved but does essentially add an intermediate step, where a grunt 'build' target is a step used to 'compile' (just vulcanize) app/ into build/, and the old build target became 'dist' which optimized build/ into dist/.
The intention is that development is now done in build/ and the optimized code in dist/ is used to build packages (crx) for distribution.

It's still somewhat unfinished and certainly isn't ready to push upstream to the yeoman generator, but I hope it helps someone.